# MediaPlayer pausing and playing error

Tags: java, android, xml, if-statement, media-player

I'm building an application for Android with Java and XML. The user of the app must be able to listen to a tune and also pause it. So I made one button with which you can play and pause the tune. I made a function in which the `src` of the `ImageView` must be changed. However Eclipse gives me an error at the `mp.start()` and the `mp.pause()`, which says: *"mp cannot be resolved"*.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong right now and I hope somebody can help me.

Java code:

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Level01vraag01 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    int playknopvariable = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.vraaglayout);
        setupButtonClickListeners();
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Level01vraag01.this, R.raw.mcdonalds);
    }

    private void setupButtonClickListeners() {
        ImageView playsoundButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.playsoundbutton);
        playsoundButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void klikopplaybutton() {
        if (playknopvariable == 0) {
            mp.start();
            playknopvariable = 1;
            playsoundButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.playsoundbutton);
        } else {
            mp.pause();
            playknopvariable = 0;
            playsoundButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.playsoundbutton:
            klikopplaybutton();
            break;
        }
```

XML code:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/playsoundbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/guessbutton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
    android:src="@drawable/playsoundbutton" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That because I think you have declared and instantiated mp on the onCreate method and it is not accessible in klikopplaybutton() method.

Try something like this.

```
public class Level01vraag01 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    int playknopvariable = 0;
    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.vraaglayout);
        setupButtonClickListeners();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(Level01vraag01.this, R.raw.mcdonalds);

    }

private void setupButtonClickListeners()
{
    ImageView playsoundButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.playsoundbutton);
    playsoundButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

**UPDATE** for ERRORS on your ImageView.

You are getting an error in your playsoundButton ImageView object because you again declared it and executed the findViewById in setupButtonClickListeners method and it is not acessible in klikopplaybutton method.

Try this one.

```
public class Level01vraag01 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    int playknopvariable = 0;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    ImageView playsoundButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.vraaglayout);
        setupButtonClickListeners();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(Level01vraag01.this, R.raw.mcdonalds);

    }

    private void setupButtonClickListeners(){
        playsoundButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.playsoundbutton);
        playsoundButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void klikopplaybutton(){

        if (playknopvariable == 0){
           mp.start();
           playknopvariable = 1;
           playsoundButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.playsoundbutton);
       }else{
           mp.pause();
           playknopvariable = 0;
           playsoundButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
   }

   public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.playsoundbutton:
            klikopplaybutton();
        break;
   }

}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks man, you solved that problem but now I get an error at the "playsoundButton" when I try to change the source of the imageView.

Comment: You mean at what line th error is? The error is at this code:

playsoundButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);              


It says "playsoundButton cannot be resolved"

Comment: You might one to read more about the MediaPlayer methods. It has particularly release() method. You can read it here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html